# Grid not stretching over the whole dockpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, user-controls, grid

I have an issue making a grid (list of users) not stretching vertically into the whole available space of the dock panel.

My simplified grid is in a UserControl:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="Black">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <DataGrid Name="UserDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding UsersProfiles, Mode=OneWay}" 
               AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Id" Binding="{Binding UserIdentifier}"
                                   Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
         </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
```

My window is as simple as:

```
<DockPanel Background="Yellow">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding UserView}" Background="Red"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The ViewModel behind the main window returns correctly the userControl via UserView.
The Grid is stretched horizontally but not vertically. Why?

Comment: The problem may be that the DockPanel itself is not stretched vertically into its container. I would suggest first that you add a `DockPanel.Dock=` attribute to the `ContentControl` element and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't stretched vertically? Change the `Background` color of the `DataGrid` to test. The DataGrid Rows won't stretch, however the DataGrid itself will. If you want the row items to stretch vertically you'll need to either implement your own `Template`, or use a different control such as an `ItemsControl` with its `ItemsPanel` set to your `Grid`

Answer (score 0):

You may simply need to specify `LastChildFill` to `True` on your `DockPanel`. Otherwise it's probably that the `DataGrid` doesn't resize since it's not designed to take all available vertical space.

In the latter case, you can do:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: No success with     

     <DockPanel Background="Yellow" LastChildFill="True">
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding UserProfileView}" Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
 
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <DataGrid >
    <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <Grid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Id" Binding="{Binding UserIdentifier}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>

Comment: Sorry for incorrect formatting I am a newbie. Tried with a new empty project with just my code (none for you suggestions) and it works. Damned irritating... it's the same - almost my first project is much more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. My fault. All my xaml had Height = 30 in code behind. What a bad luck! that started with a copy / paste. Thanks guys for contributing!